# sql left join where you combine right side field instances into a single csv column result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have sql left join where there is are multiple right side hits for every join.  Instead if returning a row for each right side match i'd like to return a single row where the multiple right side matches are combined into a csv [ comma separated value result ].

```
-- instead of this that produces a left.id row for every associated tag entry . . .
select left.id, left.name, right.tag from support_request left 
join support_request_tags right on left.id = right.support_request_id

-- need something like this that produces one left.id row with csv column of all associated tag entries . . .
select left.id, left.name, right.<csv list of all associated tags ???> from support_request left 
join support_request_tags right on left.id = right.support_request_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT left.id, 
       left.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(right.tag) AS tags_CSV_list 
FROM support_request left 
JOIN support_request_tags right ON left.id = right.support_request_id
GROUP BY left.id, 
         left.name;
```

Comment: @nbk Do you mean that the aliases must be quoted? this is a pattern, not a query, I'm sure that in practice the names will differ.